# How can I access files on an Android from Windows 7?

Tags: android, vb.net

I'm writing an app in VB that I would like to be able to grab files from multiple systems on my network, including Windows and Android systems.  Say for example, I want my app to catalog all the music files on a PC, a Win7 laptop, an Android phone, and an Android tablet, the information will then be stored to a DB or written to an XML file or something (haven't decided on this part yet).  On the Windows systems, I can get the files easily from a shared folder or network drive, but I'm stuck at incorporating the Android file systems into it.  Also, everything is wireless through a router.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Android OS has no built-in network file sharing capabilities, you're looking for a media server (e.g. upnp) or file server app on android.  Some apps provide SMB shares of the local file system, but be aware that the android permissions model doesn't necessarily allow access to all the data in all apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android SDK is distributed with a set of developer tools. In these tools, there is an executable called `adb` which stands for Android Debugging Bridge. Download the developer tools and add the path to the executable to your PATH variable. Then, in command prompt, you can just you can use `adb shell` to execute command line instructions (such as `ls`, which lists a directory's contents) on the device and retrieve their results from standard input. Using the adb, you could also add or remove files from the device.

I am not sure if VB loads your path variable when you do system instructions. If it does not, you will need to execute the adb using the full path to it (C:\< path >\adb.exe)

Note: Using the adb requires USB Debugging to be enabled on your device. To enable this, on most devices, you can simply visit settings, scroll down to developer options, and enable debugging. On some devices, you need to go to Settings, About Phone, and tap "Kernel Version" several times to enable developer mode. Then you can enable debugging the same way as above.

Comment: adb can be used over wifi?

Comment: got adb running over wifi and able to shell out from my app to do a file list (of sorts).  thanks for the assist!